# Security issue in Visual Studio 2015 setup project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, setup-project

I have security issue when executing setup project created in Visual Studio 2015.

The app output directory is not accessible regardless if the app is installed for all users and current user.

I did some research and found that it is possible to set the app install directory access but I could not make the app run from the setup.

Comment: Is the installer manifested as "RequireAdministrator" or at least it ask for elevation during the process?

Comment: Installer does run as Administrator. The app is successfully installed, it is just cannot be accessed or even the app folder cannot be opened.

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand on Alejandro's comment. Let's assume the install directory is the Program Files directory, although this applies to many other shared folders too.

Limited users have never been able to create or update files in that folder. Nobody noticed on XP because everyone was administrator all the time. But on UAC machines even an administrator does not get administrator privilege without elevation. So by definition, because that program updates files in that location then it requires elevation, which is why it needs a manifest with RequireAdministrator as Alejandro says. If you want your program to be available to limited users then use a folder that limited users can write to (such as User's Application Data in a VS Setup Project).

Installing an app for all users (Everyone in Visual Studio) does not turn off security for the installed app. That would be a security breach. Limited users do not get write access to (say) the Program Files folder just because they're running an app installed for all users, and even if you are an admin account your program is running as limited user unless you ran it from an elevated prompt or you built it with an elevation manifest.